# Sending json from template to view in django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, django

I want to send json data via ajax fr4om template to view and put it directly in database.
the problem is that the data does not reach the view.
(when i insert numbers it works but when i try to insert my json data: `json_data['x']`,`json_data['y']`,`json_data['z']` it doesn't works)
any ideas ??

url.py

```
url(r'^ajaxexample_json$', 'myApp.views.ajax'),
```

Template:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json",
url : "http://localhost:8000/ajaxexample_json",
data : { x: "1", y: "2" , z: "3" },
dataType: "json"
});
```

view.py

```
def ajax(request):
    db = db_connection().db;
    db_manager= db_management(db);
    json_data=json.loads(request.body)
    db_manager.insert_access_point(json_data['x'],json_data['y'],json_data['z'])
    db.close()                                      
    return HttpResponse('Ok')
```

Comment: do you define `json_data` before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery will not take an object and turn it into JSON. You must do that yourself using a function like [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
data : JSON.stringify({ x: "1", y: "2" , z: "3" }),
```